# Large volume distribution across windows

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I am working on developing an storage, retrieval and archiving program.

I want to manage large count of files (0.5 million per day). Each file will be of size 20kb to 30kb in size.

I have had situation where if I put too many files in single folder, accessing that folder via windows explorer or via program is slower.

I have seen some solutions (don't know how they do it), where they have folder like 0,1,2,...99 and they distribute files across with equal count or size.

Is there any algorithm or .net program which I can use to do same.

Thanks in anticipation,...

Comment: Do you control the filenames being used to store them (or does the caller determine that)? Does https://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem help?

Comment: Caller determines... but those will be unique always.

Comment: How long are the filenames likely to be?

Comment: files names are 40-50 characters long.. e.g.: xxxxxxxxxx_xnnnnnnnnnnnnnn_xxx_nn_nnn.xxx (x=char, n=number)

Comment: You will also want to make sure 8.3 name generation is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using git approach. Calculate a hash from file name and use its first several bytes as directory name. This would ensure pretty even file distribution across the directories:

```
public static string GetDirName(string fileName)
{
    if (hashAlgo == null)
        hashAlgo = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

    return BitConverter.ToString(
        hashAlgo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName))
            .Take(2).ToArray()
    );
}
```

Full demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xlu4P8